# Check neighbour pixels Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a `A` which is 640x1 cell. where the value of each cell `A(i,1)` varies from row to row, for example `A(1,1) =[]`, while `A(2,1)=[1]` and `A(3,1)=[1,2,3]`.
There is another matrix `B` of size 480x640, where the row_index `(i)` of vector `A` corresponds to  the col_index of matrix `B`. While the cell value of each row in vector `A` corresponds to the row_index in matrix `B`. For example, A(2,1)=[1] this means col_2 row_1 in matrix `B`, while A(3,1)=[1,2,3] means col_3 rows 1,2&3 in matrix `B`.
What I'm trying to do is to for each non-zero value in matrix `B` that are referenced from vector `A`, *I want to check whether there are at least 4 other neighbors that are also referenced from vector `A`*. The number neighbors of each value are determined by a value `N`.
 For example, this is a part of matrix `B` where all the zeros"just to clarify, as in fact they may be non-zeros" are the neighbors of pixel `X` when `N=3`:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   X   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

As shown, because `N=3`, all these zeros are pixel `X`'s neighbors. So if more than 4 neighbor pixels are found in vector `A` then do something e.g `G=1` if not then `G=0`;
So if anyone could please advise. And please let me know if any more clarification is needed.

Comment: Your notation doesn't seem quite right. Do you mean you have a cell array `A`?

Comment: @TryHard Thanks for your comment. `A` is a 640x1 cell.

Comment: @TryHard  This is a link showing `A` https://www.dropbox.com/s/64b47gztw8flj3q/ret.mat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do is to convert your cell of indices `A` to a logic matrix `Amat`. This makes it easier to check how many neighbours are included in `A`.

Here is a solution that uses this conversion. I hope the comments are enough to make it understandable.

```
clear all
clc

nCols = 7;
nRows = 6;

N = 3; %// Number of neighbours
M = 4; %// Minimum number of wanted connections

%// Create cell of indices A
A = cell(nCols,1);
A{1} = [];
A{2} = 1;
A{3} = [1 2 3];
A{4} = [2 5];
A{5} = 3;
A{6} = [3 5];
A{7} = [1 4 6];

%// Generate radom data B
%// (There is a 50% probability for each element of B to be zero)
Bmax = 17;
B = (randi(2,nRows,nCols)-1).*(randi(Bmax,nRows,nCols));

%// Convert the cell A to a logic matrix Amat
Amat = zeros(size(B));
for ii = 1:nCols
    Amat(A{ii},ii) = 1;
end

A
B
Amat

for ii = 1:nCols
    for jj = A{ii}
        if B(jj,ii)>0

            %// Calculate neighbour indices with a lower bound of 1
            %// and an upper bound of nCols or nRows
            col_lim_low = max(1,ii-N);
            col_lim_high = min(nCols,ii+N);
            row_lim_low = max(1,jj-N);
            row_lim_high = min(nRows,jj+N);

            %// Get the corresponding neighbouring-matrix from Amat
            A_neighbours = ...
                Amat(row_lim_low:row_lim_high,col_lim_low:col_lim_high);

            %// Check the number of neighbours against the wanted number M
            if sum(A_neighbours(:)) > 1 + M
                %# do something
                fprintf('We should do something here at (%d,%d)\n',jj,ii)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The following is a printout from one run of the code.

```
A = 

    []
    [         1]
    [1x3 double]
    [1x2 double]
    [         3]
    [1x2 double]
    [1x3 double]


B =

     1     5     0     0    11     0    16
     0    13    13     0     0     0     9
     0     0     0     5     0     0     0
     3     8    16    16     0     2    12
     0     0     5     0     9     9     0
    12    13     0     6     0    15     0


Amat =

     0     1     1     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1

We should do something here at (1,2)
We should do something here at (2,3)
We should do something here at (5,6)
We should do something here at (4,7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a one-to-one correspondence between `A` and `B`, there is no need to work on `A`. B is a logical matrix (0 if not referenced in `A`, 1 if referenced). You can therefore apply a simple `filter2` function counting the number of active neighbors within the 8 closest elements.

Here is the code

```
B = rand(10,10);                %generate binary matrix
h = [1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1];        %filter to be applied
filter2(h,B,'same')>=4 & B>0    %apply filter on B, count minimum of 4 neighbors, if only B>1
```

---

**EDIT**

To transform a cell array `B` into binary presence (0=empty, 1=not empty), use of `cellfun`is straightforward

```
B = ~cellfun(@isempty,B);
```

And see [Armo's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436329/change-the-format-of-a-cell-array-matlab) to your previous question for how to create B based on A.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the problem how can I create B which is a logical matrix (0 if not referenced in A, 1 if referenced)?